# When I train neural network using EC2 instance, where I need to store train dataset?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have over 100 GB image datasets.

1. Should they generally be stored in "storage of EC2 instance" or "S3 storage"?
2. When I store train dataset in EC2 instance, will dataset stay in that instance as long as I don't terminate the instance (I should "stop" instance to preserve uploaded dataset in EC2 instance)?
3. When I should store dataset in S3, then I need to mount S3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 is the cheapest option for data storage that you have on AWS so I would suggest you to store the training data there.

You can't really store data in an EC2 instance, you can store them in the underlying volume storage. That can be either EBS volumes or Instance-store volumes.

If you are using EBS volumes, then you can configure how they will behave once you terminate the instance, so you can specify whether to delete them or not, which means that even if you terminate the EC2 instance, you can still keep the volumes if you choose so.

This is not possible in case of Instance-store volumes. Those are automatically deleted when you terminate the EC2 instance and if you are running instance-stored backed EC2 instance (EC2 instance with instance-instance store root volume), then you can't stop it, and if any failure happens, then all the data on ephemeral instance-store volumes are lost.

If you care only about the result of the operation, then you can upload the result to S3 and terminate instance.

Yes, you can mount S3 bucket to your EC2 instance or you can just send the data using S3 API.

So my suggestion is, store the data in S3. When you are ready to process it, spin up EC2 instance, pull data from S3 (if your S3 and EC2 instance are sitting in the same region, this data transfer is for free). Process the data and store the result back to S3. Terminate the instance (or stop it if you need the same setup for the next task, or create an AMI of it).

Another thing to consider here is the type of volumes that you choose (SSD vs. HDD). It may be more reasonable to go with throughput-optimized volumes than general SSD (and of course the type of the instance but that you need to measure how your selected instance is performing and whether to scale it up a bit or change the type).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instruction. As you said, using EC2 instance with mounted S3 is good.

Answer (score 2):

have you considered using Amazon SageMaker? Store your data in S3, train and deploy on fully-managed infrastructure. A lot of customers find that it's quite easier than managing your own EC2 instances :)

https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/

I'd love to hear your feedback and answer any questions.

Comment: Hey, I saw your instruction about how to use EC2 instance with AMI on YouTube before reading your answer. That's very clear explanation.

I tried to use SageMaker. Even if it looks very convenient for some cases, but it turns out it's too high level service for my task and code,
for example, using Estimator() when I prepare to start training, fit() when I start training, OS is red hat distribution which I'm not familiar with,  and it seems like there are 2 environments that I should manage (env for Jupyter notebook, env where code runs because I use package of .py files with entry file) etc

Comment: It finally turns out at the moment that it's more comfortable to use EC2 instance and a mounted S3 onto that EC2 instance.

Comment: That's fine :) Use whatever works best for you. Feel free to ping me later on if you have feedback or questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use EBS volume as well and then mount it then if the instance stops your volume will need to be mounted again. S3 File system will give you the same functionality. I would not store 100 GB of data in S3 and use S3 SDK as the GET requests on many small files can get very expensive.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I'll also inspect the way you referred about how to use EBS volume.